# PHP: Edit 'from' in email sending script

Tags: php, email

I have a simple PHP script that I hook up to my HTML forms to and use to send emails.

However, I am not very clear on how to edit it so I can add a reply email address (eg: 'noreply@mysite.com'). I've tried looking online and messing around but I havent got it to work.

Currently I just get 'Nobody' or 'Mail sever' appearing in the from field in my email client.

Would anyone tell me how I can do this correctly?

```
mail( "$webmaster_email", "Site inquiry",
   "From: $email  \n Name: $name \n
To:  $contact\n
Phone: $phone\n 
Message: $message\n ");
```

Comment: obviously you didn't start by looking at the PHP docs, which tell you exactly what you need to do: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taken from the php manual pages:

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

PS: Developpers first rule is "Man pages are your best friend"

Comment: +1 Developers first rule is "Man pages are your best friend"